# Error creating bean named `conversionServicePostProcessor` when using spring-boot-admin-server

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, spring-boot-admin

I was trying to enable Spring boot admin server for my application. The default settings work perfectly fine but when I attempt to enable security, I am getting following error:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> The bean 'conversionServicePostProcessor', defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class],
>   could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/reactive/WebFluxSecurityConfiguration.class]
>   and overriding is disabled.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
>   spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I am using the latest SNAPSHOT version of `spring-boot-admin-starter-server` (2.2.0-SNAPSHOT). Here is my security configuration:

```
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class AdminServerSecurityConfigurations(val adminServerProperties: AdminServerProperties) {

    @Bean
    fun adminServerSecurityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain = http
            // @formatter:off
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("${adminServerProperties.contextPath}/assets/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("${adminServerProperties.contextPath}/login").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("${adminServerProperties.contextPath}/login").and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("${adminServerProperties.contextPath}/logout").and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            // @formatter:on
            .csrf().disable()
            .build()


    @Bean
    fun notifyLogger(instanceRepository: InstanceRepository) = LoggingNotifier(instanceRepository)

}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a pull request to update the documentation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14069

> For Reactive WebSockets,
> {spring-reference}web-reactive.html#webflux-websocket[Spring WebFlux] offers rich support,
> which is accessible through the `spring-boot-starter-webflux` module.
> See the `spring-boot-sample-websocket-reactive` sample project to see how WebSockets may
> be implemented using Spring WebFlux.

it turns out that using webflux and websocket leads to conflicts.

also in this pull request was denied in the resolution of the conflict
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14810

for reactive websocket see this sample https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-reactive-websockets

Comment: Thanks @Sergey. It's never too late to answer a question. Will certainly be useful to everyone facing this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and was able solve it by adding

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

to my application.properties.

Sounds like a workaround and it was also only necessary if I deployed it as WAR -- as a standalone application the exception never occured.

Comment: Unlike you, for me, the exception was thrown when packaging was Jar.

Comment: This is working for me as well but not making me happy though.

Answer (score 2):

As above it is the conflict between web flux and reactive. Update your application properties to include the following to neatly solve this issue:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
```

I don't believe allow bean overrides would be a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error, after Reimport All Mavne Projects(Intellij IDE) it works fine for me. Here my detailed input on this issue [here](https://boomirajp.blogspot.com/2022/01/error-creating-bean-with-name.html)